# Select images with intent

Tags: android

I am trying to upload image file to php server. I created a button which intents to all the images folder

```
Intent image = new Intent ();
image.setAction (Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
image.addCategory (Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
image.setType ("image/*");
startActivityForResult (Intent.createChooser (image, "SELECT image"), 1);
```

The problem is that the image file only uploads when selected from gallery folder. It only see images selected from gallery folder as valid file. I want the application to be able to upload from any image folder like images folder, downloads folder, photos folder etc.

Comment: "The problem is that the image file only uploads when selected from gallery folder" -- there is no code in your question related to this. You might wish to add the relevant code to your question, such as your `onActivityResult()` implementation. Also, please note that `ACTION_GET_CONTENT` has nothing much to do with files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you startActivityForResult(intent) you have to get its result after starting that like this

### first of all create your intent

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setType("image/*");
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,getResources().getString(R.string.selectPic)), PICK_IMAGE);
```

### then listen for its result

```
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
    {
         if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
             if (data == null) {
                 //Display an error
                 return;
             }
                 InputStream inputStream = this.getContentResolver().openInputStream(data.getData());

     }
```

now you have an inputStream from your selected image next step is to getting its bytes and create a bitmap of that.

good luck !